# RequiredAttribute not preventing Empty string entries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want to catch blank entries on a property I have in my model. I added the Required DataAnnotation above the property hoping that it would catch this when I try to update the value. However when I update it, it just sets the property to null and continues without any issues.
I also tried [RegularExpression] and [StringLength] validation attributes but these are also just bypassed.

The Model:

```
public class CaseDescriptionModel
{
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description:")]
    [Required]
    public string CaseDescription { get; set; }

    public CaseDescriptionModel() { }

    public CaseDescriptionModel(Case case)
    {
        if (case == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("case");
        }

        CaseId = case.ID;
        CaseDescription = case.Description;
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@model Models.CaseDescriptionModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
    @Html.StandardForm(this, "", false, true, "UpdateDescription", "Case",
     @<div>
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CaseId)

         <table class="full-width">
             <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td class="ColumnOneStyle">
                         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CaseDescription)
                     </td>
                     <td class="ColumnTwoStyle" style="float:right;">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CaseDescription)
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>  

         @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "" })

         <table style="float: right;">
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     @item.Submit("SUBMIT")
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @Html.ButtonLinkAction("btnCancel", "CANCEL", "Return to case", "Details", "Case", "btnSecondary", new { id = Model.CaseId })
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
     )
</div>
```

The Controller Method

```
public ActionResult UpdateCase(CaseDescriptionModel model)
        {
            if (model == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
            }

            var case= DAL.GetCase(model.CaseId);

            DAL.UpdateCaseDescription(model.CaseId, model.CaseDescription);

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = model.CaseId });
        }
```

Comment: Did you have `ModelState.IsValid` check in your controller method to verify if the model is valid?

Comment: @Borka I added the Controller Method, where would I need to add that check?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of context first: You need to manually check if the model state is valid. The model state will be validated against the requirements you have in the ViewModel, like the `Required` attribute.

To check if the model is valid you'll need to add the following lines in your controller method

```
public ActionResult UpdateCase(CaseDescriptionModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
    }

    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // maybe do some dropdown list loading if you have before the view
        return View();
    }

    var case = DAL.GetCase(model.CaseId);

    DAL.UpdateCaseDescription(model.CaseId, model.CaseDescription);

    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = model.CaseId });
}
```

What will happen here, if the model is not valid, the ModelState will already be populated with the error messages of the incorrect fields. By returning the View, you will display the user the same view that they were previously on, and the `ValidationSummary` control that you already have will be populated with the errors from the model state validation.

Hope this helps.